# Is there any way to get DJI Phantom 3's video stream to Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dji-sdk

I have a DJI Phantom 3 Professional and I am developing an Android application . I would like to get the video stream from the drone and use it in Unity 3D. Is there any way to that?

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking here: [Fix for DJI GO Android](https://forum.dji.com/thread-77964-1-1.html) Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is about the connection issue. I am looking for a solution to transfer the video stream to Unity 3D Game Engine. So this is not the answer I am looking for.